# codename one android Failed registering for push notifications on firebase getting INVALID_PARAETERS error string back

Tags: codenameone

I registered with Firebase for android, downloaded the google-services.json file and added it to the native/andriod directory.

On the Emulator everything works fine, but on an Andriod device the Push Registration fails with Error code 0, INVALID_PARAMETERS as given by the pushRegistrationError callback method.

Is there something wrong with my registration on Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to define the GCM sender ID as `gcm.sender_id=GCM_SENDER_ID`. This is covered in the guide [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/push.html) but we might need to highlight it further.